# error while booting linux using busybox and qemu

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, busybox

I have been trying to build kernel using busybox and qemu by following this tutorial (https://gist.github.com/ncmiller/d61348b27cb17debd2a6c20966409e86) but after booting i am getting this error

[    1.521955] Kernel Offset: 0x33c00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    1.524625] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---

i tried following the tutorial but but didn't get the desired result instead got errors.